# Connecting remotely to an Sql server inside a LAN

Tags: sql-server-2008, router

Hello everyone,

I am using sql server 2008 inside my home lan. I've configured it to accept remote connections and I can now connect to the server from other pcs inside the lan.

The problems rises when I try connecting to the server from a computer outside of my home lan. I've disabled my router's firewall and I've configured a virtual server on port 1433 forwarding to the correct lan ip. What's wrong? why is it not working?

Thank you very much for your help~!

Comment: This is really more appropriate for serverfault - it a networking issue rather than a programming issue.

Comment: Also, if you want to see this answered you should at least post the error message shown when you try to connect, and share what tools you're using to test this.

Comment: This is the error I keep getting:
a network related or instance specific error occured while establishing connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL SERVER is configued to allow remote connections. (provider : Sql network interfaces, error: 25- Connection string is not valid)

Comment: I think you asked this same question yesterday here? Anyway, please post the connection string as that is what the error you are getting is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the SQL Server Browser service on your server